# JQtouch Ajax not able to send the same request twice

Tags: ajax, jqtouch

Im creating an app using JQ mobile, it has a list of items and you select one and it send the goes to another page that does the ajax request.the problem is that if I go back select a different item from the list and then go back to the first item and select it. it will not show the item again just the previously selected item.

here is my code

```
<div id="get">

    <script>


    $.ajax({    
        url: "http://s336087876.onlinehome.us/pmc/newapp/php/showCoupon.php?id=" + test,
        cache: true,
        success: function(data) {
        $('.coupon').html(data);
    },
        // Error handler
        error: function(req, status, err){
         alert('not working');
        }
    });

</script>
```

Also here is a link so you can see what it is doing.

http://s336087876.onlinehome.us/pmc/newapp/html/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "cacheGetRequests: false" in initialization. for more info http://code.google.com/p/jqtouch/issues/detail?id=35